# iOS9 Localized Search Indexing

Tags: ios, ios9

I'm implementing a couple of NSUserActivities for the iOS9 search index. I have made them all public by setting the boolean
`activity.eligibleForPublicIndexing = YES;`

As I understand it from watching the WWDC session on Search indexing (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=709) 
18.40 - 19.00. 
A public NSUserActivity could potentially show up on another users device.

My question is, how does this work with localization? If I index an NSUserActivity with a swedish localized title for example, could that swedish title show up for another user who doesn't have the same locale?

Thanks in advance!